# How to return and store a document in a value with pouchdb?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pouchdb

I use ionic 4 with pouchdb.
I would like to get value from a document.

I wish to get the id_observateur value from a pouchdb document.
I tried to use arrows functions but it does not work

```
let get_observateur = () => {
     PouchDB.plugin(PouchDBFind);
     PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-adapter-cordova-sqlite'));
     this.observateurlocal= new PouchDB('observateurlocal', {adapter: 
      'cordova-sqlite'});

       this.observateurlocal.get('observateurlocal').then((doc) =>{
            return doc.id_observateur;

             });
            }; 
         // Call the function 
         console.log(get_observateur);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
let get_observateur = async () => {
  PouchDB.plugin(PouchDBFind);
  PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-adapter-cordova-sqlite'));
  this.observateurlocal = new PouchDB('observateurlocal', {
    adapter: 'cordova-sqlite'
  });
 return await this.observateurlocal.get('observateurlocal');
};

console.log(await get_observateur);
```

Comment: It gives this error : error TS1308: 'await' expression is only allowed within an async function

Comment: I did this : this.observateur = this.observateurlocal.get('observateurlocal').then( res => res.id_observateur);
console.log(this.observateur); but i have the result in an array as ZoneAwarePromise object! It seems like a promise